# OBJ_FIBO: ObjectGetValueByTime-alternative?

Tags: mql5

I would like my MQL5 EA to read the prices of a fibonacci object's retracement levels (assuming the same EA created this very fibo object before). Unfortunately, `ObjectGetValueByTime` doesn't work for fibonaccis. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply get the two kep points by ObjectGetDouble() and then compute the levels (0.618, 1.618 etc) yourself - more reliable and it is faster then getting those values from the chart

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just for curiosity: would it be possible to get the values from the chart? For example in case the Fibonacci has been drawn into the chart manually ...

Comment: yes, loop over all objects on the chart to get only OBJ_FIBO and then do all manipulations